# XSLT Question on grouping by more than one element and Summarizing accordingly

Tags: xslt

I have an XML1 that I want to transform so that it  groups by the repeating tags and summarize the quantities accordingly

```
        <t>
       <Equipment>
        <lin_id>C18312</lin_id>
        <lindesc>hhhh</lindesc>
        <qty>5</qty>
       </Equipment>
       <Equipment>
        <lin_id>C18345</lin_id>
        <lindesc>hhhh1</lindesc>
        <qty>22</qty>
       </Equipment>
       <Equipment>
        <lin_id>C18378</lin_id>
        <lindesc>hhhh2</lindesc>
        <qty>43</qty>
       </Equipment>
       <Equipment>
        <lin_id>C18378</lin_id>
        <lindesc>hhhh2</lindesc>
        <qty>208</qty>
       </Equipment>
        </t>
```

Now, I need to have the following output, which is Grouping by LIN_ID and linedesc

```
        <top>
      <Results>
        <LIN_ID>C18312</LIN_ID>
        <lindesc>hhhh</lindesc>
        <Count>5</Count>
      </Results>
      <Results>
        <LIN_ID>C18345</LIN_ID>
        <lindesc>hhhh1</lindesc>
        <Count>22</Count>
      </Results>
      <Results>
        <LIN_ID>C18378</LIN_ID>
        <lindesc>hhhh2</lindesc>
      <Count>251</Count>
      </Results>
        </top>
```

With the following code I almost achieve the goal

```
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
            <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:template match="/*">
              <top>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="Equipment/lin_id" group-by=".">
                    <Results>      
                       <LIN_ID>
                        <xsl:sequence select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                      </LIN_ID>  
                      <Count>
                        <xsl:sequence select="sum(current-group()/../qty)"/>
                      </Count>
                    </Results>
                  </xsl:for-each-group>
              </top>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the current output, please note it is not bringing the second repeating element (lindesc)

```
        <top>
       <Results>
          <LIN_ID>C18312</LIN_ID>
          <Count>5</Count>
       </Results>
       <Results>
          <LIN_ID>C18345</LIN_ID>
          <Count>22</Count>
       </Results>
       <Results>
          <LIN_ID>C18378</LIN_ID>
          <Count>251</Count>
       </Results>
        </top>
```

Comment: You specify your stylesheet as `version="1.0"`, but you use verson 2.0 functions. What XSLT version can you use?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a *well-formed* input XML like...

```
<root>
    <t>
        <Equipment>
            <lin_id>C18312</lin_id>
            <lindesc>hhhh</lindesc>
            <qty>5</qty>
        </Equipment>
        <Equipment>
            <lin_id>C18345</lin_id>
            <lindesc>hhhh1</lindesc>
            <qty>22</qty>
        </Equipment>
        <Equipment>
            <lin_id>C18378</lin_id>
            <lindesc>hhhh2</lindesc>
            <qty>43</qty>
        </Equipment>
        <Equipment>
            <lin_id>C18378</lin_id>
            <lindesc>hhhh2</lindesc>
            <qty>208</qty>
        </Equipment>
    </t>
</root>
```

...you can use the following XSLT-2.0 stylesheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/root/t">
        <top>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Equipment" group-by="lin_id">
                <Results>      
                    <LIN_ID><xsl:sequence select="current-grouping-key()"/></LIN_ID>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="lindesc" />
                    <Count><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/qty)"/></Count>
                </Results>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </top>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...to get the desired result:

```
<top>
   <Results>
      <LIN_ID>C18312</LIN_ID>
      <lindesc>hhhh</lindesc>
      <Count>5</Count>
   </Results>
   <Results>
      <LIN_ID>C18345</LIN_ID>
      <lindesc>hhhh1</lindesc>
      <Count>22</Count>
   </Results>
   <Results>
      <LIN_ID>C18378</LIN_ID>
      <lindesc>hhhh2</lindesc>
      <Count>251</Count>
   </Results>
</top>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have the following output, which is Grouping by LIN_ID and linedesc

If you want to group by **both** `lin_id` and `linedesc`then you should be doing (in XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Equipment" group-by="concat(lin_id, '|', linedesc)">
```

or (in XSLT 3.0):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Equipment" group-by="lin_id, linedesc)" composite="yes">
```

Of course, your example is rather useless for testing this because it has no items with same `lin_id`  and different `linedesc` or vice versa. If no such items can exist, then what is point of grouping by both properties?

Note also that you say *"Grouping by LIN_ID"* but the input you show has `lin_id` elements which is not the same thing. XML is case-sensitive.

---

Then, within the `xsl:for-each-group` instruction, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="lin_id, linedesc"/>
<Count>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/qty)"/>
</Count>
```

This is assuming that `Count` should contain the total quantity of the group - which IMHO is confusing because normally "count" and "quantity" have different meanings.

Comment: Thank you very much, and yes! is confusing and will fix it.